# Javascript call to NewItem2 error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of undefined"

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model, ribbon, custom-actions

### Overview

I have a CustomAction for a button on the ribbon that calls a command in a javascript file.  The command fails in the inplview.debug.js file on the following lines (1745 - 1748) in the GetFocusInfo method:

```
while((focusBack.tagName !="A") && (focusBack.tagName !="BODY"))
{
    focusBack=focusBack.parentNode;
}
```

The problem is on the 2nd iteration, focusBack is null.  I assume something about the event I'm passing is wonky.  If I call the method directly from the javascipt console, it executes correctly.

I eventually gave up and used `window.SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({url:this.url});`

But I'm still curious as to what's going on here.  Maybe it's more appropriate as a general javascript question on stackoverflow.

Here is my custom action:

```
<CustomAction 
    Location="ScriptLink" 
    ScriptSrc="/_layouts/ASAP/CustomActions.js" 
    Sequence="1100" />    

<CustomAction
    Id="NewSupplementalDocument"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
    RegistrationType="ContentType"
    RegistrationId="0x0100C44D4F1333A44FC9893DC3CFC16541A0"
    Sequence="1200" >        
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls._children">
      <Button   Id="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.GISRowSupplemental"
         Alt="Supplemental Button"
         Sequence="5"
         Command="New_Supplemental"
         labelText="New Suppl"
         ToolTipTitle="Add a suplemental document to this GIS row."
         Image32by32="/_layouts/1033/images/formatmap32x32.png"
         Image32by32Top="-320"
         Image32by32Left="-64"
         TemplateAlias="o1" />
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>      
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler Command="New_Supplemental"
        CommandAction="javascript:
            SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded (LoadCoreAndGo,'sp.js');">
    </CommandUIHandler>
  </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension>
```

Here is my javascript file:

```
var inProgress = false;
var listName = 'GIS Row Supplemental Documents';
var list;
var url;

function LoadCoreAndGo() {
    window.SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoade
      (GotoSupplementalNewFormUrl, 'Core.js');
}

function GotoSupplementalNewFormUrl() {
    if (!inProgress) {
        try {
            inProgress = true;
            var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var web = context.get_web();
            this.list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
            context.load(this.list, 'Id');
            context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,success),
                Function.createDelegate(this, fail));
        }
        catch(e) {
            alert(e);
            inProgress = false;
        }
    }
}

function success() {
    try {
        var id = String(this.list.get_id());
        this.url = '/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={' + id.toUpperCase() + '}';
        window.NewItem2(event, this.url); <-- This is where it fails        
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
    finally {
        inProgress = false;
    }
}

function fail(sender, args) {
    alert('Operation failed: ' + args.get_message());
    inProgress = false;
}
```

Any ideas on what the issue might be?

Comment: Try to check if your global variable names do not conflict with OOB sharepoint variables. Sometimes it leads to magic javascript errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need just to display a modal dialog?

I'd recommend to use [SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058.aspx) directly rather than leveraging undocumented NewItem2 function. Example code:

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({
    url: '/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={' + id.toUpperCase() + '}',
    title: 'Upload supplemental document'
});
```

P.S. Btw, I don't think you need to pre-load "Core.js" file. I suspect sp.js is already dependent from "Core.js" and so it will be loaded anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about Core.js.  I got a little carried away trying to figure out the issue ;)  I mention at the end of the post that I am using SP.UI.ModalDialog.  I'll move it to the beginning of the code to make it more noticeable.

Comment: Is there a way to return the uploaded document's relative path?

Comment: Yes, you should use dialogReturnValueCallback for this purpose, and analyze return value. If you have any problems with that, please, post a separate question.